# Spring Tool Suite Really Slow

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am running a Spring Boot project using the Spring Boot run configuration to run/debug the application. It is painfully slow, even on a very powerful computer. It often goes away for several seconds at time, not allowing the window to come to the front or to restoring the console back from maximized. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might make it so slow?

```
Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.8.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201703310825
Platform: Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3)
```

on a new Core i7 with 32GB of memory.

STS.ini has

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms1024m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx4096m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Comment: There could be few reasons but nothing concrete. 
Try to remove unwanted plugins under Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown, Try to remove or uncheck validations, Try to uncheck any auto builds or updates. There are few optimizer in the market if you wish to try.

Comment: After installing the latest  STS version  I am eperiencing the same **slowness** when launching / debugging a project. My specs are i7 7700HQ and 16GB of ram...

Comment: 2 Days later. Can you confirm wether you are using the dark theme in eclipse? I tried to go back to the default one and the slowness suddenty dissapeared.

Comment: Does this only happen when you first open STS or is it happening while using it?

Comment: Same problem on my side, STS is just unusable on serious projects. I tried to uninstall it / reinstall it, cleaning Eclipse, etc. Nothing changes, with STS I have to wait between 5 an 10 seconds after each save. IMO STS is doing too much work with AOP, Beans, etc. I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.1 with STS 3.9.0 RELEASE, computer i7 7700HQ, 16GB or ram, double SSD hard drive. STS is using 100% of one CPU core.

Answer (score 14):

The issue I ran into related to themes after a recent update from STS 3.7 to 3.9.5. Once I disabled theming through the following, most of the latency disappeared.

> Preferences > General > Appearance > Enable theming

Since I wanted themes (Dark), I found that the most latent operation was scrolling through the Console when a server was started, or switch to and from that view. I found the [following bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=510009#c5) reported, and had success after disabling themed scrollbars by updating the following in `e4-dark_win.css`:

```
StyledText {
    swt-scrollbar-themed: false;
[...]
```

Beyond that, I also had to disable:

> Preferences > Ansi Console

As well as:

> Run configurations (select your Spring Boot App) > Spring Boot tab > ANSI console output

Comment: Preferences > Ansi Console

was the key

Comment: @JuanMiguel When I uncheck Ansi Console the console text is messed up